# Style Android FragmentTabHost Tabs

Tags: android, styles, android-tabhost

I try to style (color, border, ...) the Tabs in a FragmentTabHost, but I could not find anything useful. Could somebody point me to a useful tutorial or some code?

Thanks

Comment: [try this](http://androidcodeblogspot.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-fragment-tab-example-bottom.html)